# Libreoffice - create relative hyperlinks for grid series

Tags: openoffice-basic

I have a grid that is set up as A1, A2, B1, B2, B3 etc. Rows run from A...Z and also AA to KG and the columns range from 1 to 1000.

Thanks to @Jim K in [LibreOffice Draw -add hyperlinks based on query table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391704/libreoffice-draw-add-hyperlinks-based-on-query-table/35410780?noredirect=1#comment58638687_35410780) we can add the hyperlinks from 1 to 1000 but I am not sure how to embed a second loop that does this?

I will be easiest if we could supply a CSV that has

```
A1, map_A1.pdf
A2, map_A2.pdf
FG89, map_FG89.pdf
```

This makes sure only the text we want is hyperlinked and it can deal with any complexity of file names. Match should be exact as well.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through letters, for example A to Z:

```vb
Sub chars_loop
    Dim cval, c
    For cval = Asc("A") to Asc("Z")
       c = Chr(cval)
       Print(c)
    Next cval
End Sub
```

As far as reading from a CSV file, there are two ways to read from files:

- The [com/sun/star/ucb/SimpleFileAccess](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/ucb/SimpleFileAccess.html) interface.
- Using classic Basic file I/O.

For an example of the latter, see [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section 5.13.  You could loop through all lines in the file with `Do While Not EOF(iNum)`.

Comment: I finally got back to this project. There is an updated pdf that has quite complex grid labeling at the following link. How can I get the text linked to relative pdf's? the maps will be like DSC_A1.pdf etc https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxjBqNsSHofKUC1KU3RITVpQZ0E